# Implement CountDownTimer from odd values

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have implemented CountDownTimer in my class and I'm able to start it with minutes such as 
`startCountDown(1*60*1000)` for one  minute. But I am unable to start it from odd values like if I want to start from 1 min 59 sec, then how do it do it?

I  tried doing `startCountDown(1*59*1000)` but that doesnt do it. It starts the timer from wrong values. What can I do to start it like  that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

60 * 1000 = 1 min

60 * 1000 + 59 * 1000 = 1 min 59 sec

So what's the problem?

Comment: I tired that but then its starting only from the remaining seconds

Comment: Got it. Was not multiplying properly. Thank you :)